# numerically solving equations using lambda functions

Tags: lambda, minimize

I want to solve an equation using scipy.minimize. It's pretty straightforward if it is a simple equation as follows. But the equation I am trying to solve is much more complicated than the one presented here, such that I would ideally use RHS and LHS to equate things. In other words, instead of lambda x: (f1(a,b,c,x)[0]-f1(a,b,c,x)[1])**2....) I want to be able to write like this, lambda x:(LHS-RHS)**2....   where both LHS and RHS are expressions depending on x, the unknown. Once I did though, python would declare x is not defined. How do I resolve this? Without using some substitution, the real equation would be pretty impossible to write. Thank you very much!

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar    
def test_david(a,b,c):
    def f1(a,b,c,x):
        return a*x-1,(b+c)*x**2   #a,b,c=[2,1,0], x**2-2*x+1=0
    #LHS=f1(a,b,c,x)[0]
    #RHS=f1(a,b,c,x)[1]
    res = minimize_scalar(lambda x: (f1(a,b,c,x)[0]-f1(a,b,c,x)[1])**2, bounds=(-5, 5), method='bounded')
    
    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it. It turns out the solution is very simple: define each side of the equation as a function such as,

```
def LHS(a,b,c,x):
    return a+b*x+c2*x**3+...  #put any close form function of x over here
def RHS(a,b,c...x):
    return x+a/x+...          #again, put any close form function of x over here
```

now write

```
res = minimize_scalar(lambda x: (LHS(a,b,c,x)-RHS(a,b,c,x))**2, bounds=(-5, 5), method='bounded')
```

and there you go!